# create stream on kafka topic using KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Below is my sample logline from kafka topic

```
2019-03-04T08:53:03.023Z "cd8cbe" 100.212.212.212 - - [20/Feb/2019:12:13:33 +0000] "GET http://dl-mysite.com/drm/PRIORITY1080/HINDI_MOVIES/somemovie.mp4/video/avc1/4/seg-1281.m4s HTTP/1.1" 200 325040 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0; Le X509 Build/DHXOSOP5801911241S)" "256" "0.000"
```

I am trying to create stream on above topic using KSQL.Below is the script which I used to create stream. After running the below stream creation script it returns me 'Stream created' message, however the select statement (select * from test_duplicate_stream;)doesn't return anything.

```
CREATE STREAM test_duplicate_stream (logArrivalTime varchar,edgeid varchar,ip varchar,col1_empty varchar,col2_empty varchar, eventdate varchar,url varchar,response_code int,response_length BIGINT,col3_empty varchar,user_agent varchar,request_length varchar, response_time varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='test_duplicate',VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED');
```

I believe 'DELIMITED' is not the right value to use here as my fields are not comma separated but space separated. What is the right way to create the stream for my logline?

Comment: What is the format of your original topic?

Comment: My topic is space delimited

Answer (score 0):

KSQL currently supports:

- JSON
- Comma-separated (delimited)
- Avro

If your data's not in one of the above formats then you won't be able to process it without changing the serialisation first.

See also [Notes on troubleshooting KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1) for when your query doesn't return data.

Comment: Thanks Robin! Currently my topic have space separated fields, is there any way I can replicate data from my current topic to another topic and change format in new topic while replicating?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to write the data in a more structured format, but if that's not an option then you're going to have to pre-process it somehow and I don't think KSQL can help currently. The challenge is that it's not just spaces as the separator, but only spaces outside of quotation marks, right? So this, whilst containing spaces, is a single value `"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0; Le X509 Build/DHXOSOP5801911241S)"`.